OpenSSL 3.0.8 FIPS compliant integration in iOS
I am building OpenSSL 3.0.8 with FIPS for an iOS device. This is my first time undertaking such a task.
Here are the steps I have followed so far:

Downloaded the OpenSSL 3.0.8 source code and configured it to build for iOS with FIPS enabled using the following script:
configure_and_build_openssl() {
    ARCH=$1
    TARGET=$2
    SDK_VERSION=$3
    SDK_PATH=$4
    PREFIX=$5

    export CROSS_TOP=$(xcode-select --print-path)/Platforms/${TARGET}.platform/Developer
    export CROSS_SDK=${TARGET}${SDK_VERSION}.sdk
    export SDKROOT=${SDK_PATH}
    export BUILD_TOOLS=$(xcode-select --print-path)/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain
    export CROSS_COMPILE="${BUILD_TOOLS}/usr/bin/"

    export CC="cc -isysroot $SDK_PATH -I$SDK_PATH/usr/include -I$SDK_PATH/usr/include/$(basename $BUILD_TOOLS)"
    export CFLAGS="-isysroot $SDK_PATH -I$SDK_PATH/usr/include -I$SDK_PATH/usr/include/$(basename $BUILD_TOOLS)"
    export LDFLAGS="-isysroot $SDK_PATH"

    # Configure and build for the specified architecture
    ./Configure ${ARCH} enable-fips no-async no-shared no-tests enable-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128 --prefix=$PREFIX --openssldir=$PREFIX
    make -j$(sysctl -n hw.ncpu)
    make install
    make clean
}


Updated the openssl.cnf file as directed in the OpenSSL FIPS module documentation

Copied libssl.a and libcrypto.a to my project, and placed openssl.cnf, fipsmodule.cnf, and fips.dylib in my project.

Enabled FIPS Mode. I wrote the following code to enable FIPS and check if it is enabled:
BOOL isFIPSModeEnabled() {
    OSSL_PROVIDER \*fips;
    OSSL_PROVIDER \*base;

    fips = OSSL_PROVIDER_load(NULL, "fips");
    if (fips == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to load FIPS provider\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    }

    base = OSSL_PROVIDER_load(NULL, "base");
    if (base == NULL) {
        OSSL_PROVIDER_unload(fips);
        printf("Failed to load base provider\n");
        return false;
    }

    if (EVP_default_properties_enable_fips(NULL, 1) == 0) {
        printf("Failed to enable FIPS mode\n");
        OSSL_PROVIDER_unload(base);
        OSSL_PROVIDER_unload(fips);
        return false;
    }

    if (EVP_default_properties_is_fips_enabled(NULL) == 1) {
        printf("FIPS mode is enabled\n");
        OSSL_PROVIDER_unload(base);
        OSSL_PROVIDER_unload(fips);
        return true;
    } else {
        printf("FIPS mode is not enabled\n");
        OSSL_PROVIDER_unload(base);
        OSSL_PROVIDER_unload(fips);
        return false;
    }
}



When I run this code, it prints "FIPS mode is enabled." However, the provider is not loading, and I receive the following error message:
Failed to load FIPS provider

C0BEC7F701000000:error:12800067:DSO support routines:dlfcn_load:could not load the shared                                      library:crypto/dso/dso_dlfcn.c:118:
C0BEC7F701000000:error:12800067:DSO support routines:DSO_load:could not load the shared library:crypto/dso/dso_lib.c:152:
C0BEC7F701000000:error:07880025:common libcrypto routines:provider_init:reason(524325):crypto/provider_core.c:912:name=fips

Why the FIPS provider is not loading? What steps I might be missing or doing incorrectly in this process?

no-shared?  I suspect it will be difficult to load shared objects if you don't build them.

The no-shared option was used intentionally during the build process to create static libraries (libssl.a and libcrypto.a). My goal is to have these static libraries included in my iOS application, along with FIPS support.
However, I am encountering an issue where the base provider loads successfully, but the FIPS provider fails to load, resulting in the given error.
Could this issue be related to using static libraries instead of shared ones? If so, could you advise on the correct approach to ensure that the FIPS provider can be loaded correctly when using static libraries?

You could first see if everything works without the no-shared option and see what artifact(s) are produced and see if an initial build using shared objects works.  You might have to produce a mixed build with some static and some shared libraries - see https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/20840

Even after using the shared configuration, the same artifacts have been produced, including openssl.conf, fipsmodule.cnf, fips.dylib, libssl.a, and libcrypto.a. After importing all these files into my project, I am still encountering the same error.

Can you can use the OPENSSL_CONFIG environment variable to give the path of the openssl.cnf  and OPENSSL_MODULES to give the fips.dylib to ur ios app ?
Xcode has a section of environments that can be passed to the app
